# Getting all user operation events via the photoeditorsdk - getOperationsStack is not a function

Tags: javascript, events, sdk, photoeditorsdk

I have setup the HTML5 SDK for the photoeditorsdk plugin and it generally works really well - I need to be able to determine if an image 'is dirty' (e.g has had any form of edit made to the original image - note I am using the latest v4 of the library/sdk

I am trying to use the following code below to output to the console the user operations however when I click the Export button and the 'export' event below is executed I get the following error:

```
var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI();
editor.on('export', function (result, editor) {
  // User has clicked export, find out what operations he used
  var stack = editor.getOperationsStack();
  console.log('User used operations:');

  stack.forEach(function (operation) {
    console.log(operation.constructor.identifier);
  });
});
```

Error

```
TypeError: editor.getOperationsStack is not a function
```

This is the exact code used from the SDK website here for events - can anyone suggest the way to get around the problem to get all the user operations and/or determine if an image 'is dirty'?
https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4/concepts/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been getting the exact same error, I've noticed that the Docs do not accurately represent the latest version (in many places).

I've managed to get the operations like so;

```
var stack = editor.operations.getStack().getStack()
```

I have no idea why the method has been removed. Frustrating they don't have issues on github, and take several days to reply to support tickets (still waiting to hear back why CORS images don't work).

Cheers

Comment: thanks Joel i'll give that a go - I agree their docs have some issues/gaps in them and they seem to push people towards the paid customer service option which is 20k or so....
I cannot test this out but will accept the answer as that is much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah exactly. I'm guessing they have a bit of a monopoly on the market now that Adobe has given up. Hopefully they'll re-add that method in at some point, but yeah, I wanted to check if anything was changed before exporting so I used this instead.

Comment: Additionally, if you end up with the same issue as me with CORS, just set the `image.crossOrigin="anonymous"`, on the image object you pass to PhotoEditor. According to their support team they apparently "can't set the cross origin property on the image".